# How to create multiple objects from the same place in java

Tags: java, swing, oop, jpanel

I'm trying to make a tower defense game and I'm having trouble making it so that when I click on one of the tower buttons at the bottom and drag to the playing area it creates a new object Tower. I have tried using an arraylist, but everytime I drag to make a new tower the previous tower erases and the new tower stays drawn on the screen.

There are a couple of classes so I will only post the ones I think are relevant. If you need the others I can put them. Sorry in advance for the length of my post.

This is the class where the events are handled
    package addison;

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Controls extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener,         ActionListener {

    Timer timer;

public static int x; //mouse's x pos
public static int y; //mouse's y pos
public static int iteration = 0;

public static String button = ""; //identifies pressed button

public static boolean pressed = false; //true if a button was pressed and not a random space
public static boolean created = false;

public static ArrayList<Tower> tower = new ArrayList<Tower>(); //arraylist of tower objects

public Controls() {

    timer = new Timer(5, this); //creates a 5ms timer
    timer.start(); //starts timer
    addMouseListener(this);
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);

    Map.paint(g); //draws map
    Hud.paint(g); //draws HUD
    TextDisplay.paint(g); //displays text
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    repaint(); //redraws graphics every 5ms
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {


}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {


}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {


}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

    if (Hud.getButton()) {

        pressed = true;
    } else {

        pressed = false;
    }

    System.out.println(pressed);
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    x = e.getX(); //gets mouse's x pos
    y = e.getY(); //gets mouse's y pos

    if (pressed) { // if the button pressed was gun man

        tower.add(iteration, new Tower(TextDisplay.description, x, y, 100, 100, 25)); //add a new tower object to the end of the arraylist

        System.out.println(tower.get(0).x);

        created = true;
        pressed = false;
    }

    iteration++;
}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {


}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

    x = e.getX(); //get mouse's x pos
    y = e.getY(); //get mouse;s y pos

    if (Hud.getButton()) {

        TextDisplay.hovering = true;
    } else {

        TextDisplay.hovering = false;
    }
}
}

package addison;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
```

this is the class where everything is drawn
    public class Map {

```
public static Rectangle mouse; //location of cursor

public Map() {

}

public static void paint(Graphics g) {

    g.setColor(new Color(255, 0, 0)); //makes mouse hit box transparent
    mouse = new Rectangle(Controls.x, Controls.y, 5, 5); //create mouse hit box
    g.fillRect(mouse.x, mouse.y, mouse.width, mouse.height); //draw mouse hit box


    g.drawRect(0, 0, 800, 450); //play area

    g.drawRect(0, 0, 800, 500); //options area

    if (Controls.created) {

        g.fillRect(Controls.tower.get(Controls.iteration).x, Controls.tower.get(0).y, 50, 50);
    }
}
}
```

This is the class where the buttons are:
    package addison;

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class Hud {

public static Rectangle gunman;
public static Rectangle laserTower;
public static Rectangle rocketLauncher;
public static Rectangle emBomb;
public static Rectangle soundGun;

public Hud() {

}

public static void paint(Graphics g) {

    gunman = new Rectangle(0, 450, 50, 50); //create gun man button
    g.fillRect(gunman.x, gunman.y, gunman.width, gunman.height); //draw gun man button

    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    laserTower = new Rectangle(50, 450, 50, 50); //create laser tower button
    g.fillRect(laserTower.x, laserTower.y, laserTower.width, laserTower.height); //draw laser tower button

    g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    rocketLauncher = new Rectangle(100, 450, 50, 50); //create rocket launcher tower
    g.fillRect(rocketLauncher.x, rocketLauncher.y, rocketLauncher.width, rocketLauncher.height); //draw rocket launcher button

    g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    emBomb = new Rectangle(150, 450, 50, 50); //creates em bomb button
    g.fillRect(emBomb.x, emBomb.y, emBomb.width, emBomb.height); //draw em bomb button

    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    soundGun = new Rectangle(200, 450, 50, 50); //create sound gun button
    g.fillRect(soundGun.x, soundGun.y, soundGun.width, soundGun.height); //draw sound gun button
}

public static boolean getButton() {

    if(Map.mouse.intersects(Hud.gunman)) {

        TextDisplay.description = "Gunman";
        return true;
    } else if (Map.mouse.intersects(Hud.laserTower)) {

        TextDisplay.description = "Laser Tower";
        return true;
    } else if (Map.mouse.intersects(Hud.rocketLauncher)) {

        TextDisplay.description = "Rocket Launcher";
        return true;
    } else if (Map.mouse.intersects(Hud.emBomb)) {

        TextDisplay.description = "E.M. Bomb";
        return true;
    } else if (Map.mouse.intersects(Hud.soundGun)) {

        TextDisplay.description = "Sound Gun";
        return true;
    } else {

        TextDisplay.description = "";
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

This is the class that makes the Tower objects:
    package addison;

```
public class Tower {

public static String type = ""; //type of tower e.g. gunman or laser tower
public static int x = 0;
public static int y = 0;
public static int range = 0; //tower range
public static int speed = 0; //tower speed
public static int sRange = 0; //tower's shrapnel range

public Tower(String a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f) {

    type = a;
    x = b;
    y = c;
    range = d;
    speed = e;
    sRange = f;
}
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

because you only paint the tower in the last iteration in the following line:

```
g.fillRect(Controls.tower.get(Controls.iteration).x, Controls.tower.get(0).y, 50, 50);
```

You need to paint all towers in the paint function

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're using `Control.iteration` as a key into your tower list. However, every time `mouseReleased` is called (whether a tower is created or not), you're incrementing `iteration`. This means that the `Controls.iteration` key in your paint handler will never refer to the newly-created tower. You're also using `Controls.tower.get(0).y` - why does this differ from the x coord?

I hope I've understood this correctly. If you're just painting the newly-created tower, why not keep a reference to that in Controls? If you're painting them all, you should loop through from 0 to `iteration - 1` and move `iteration++` inside the `if (pressed)` block.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I tried putting      `if(Controls.created) {
   for (int i = 0; i <= Controls.iteration; i++) {
   
    g.fillRect(Controls.tower.get(Controls.iteration).x, Controls.tower.get(Controls.iteration).y, 50, 50);
   }
  }` but it gives me an error right when i press the mouse button.  Then I get this error: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2

Comment: Your for statement should be 'for (int i = 0; i < Controls.iteration; i++)'. The range is from 0 to length of list minus 1.

Comment: Im still getting the same error message, but instead of 2's it's 1's. When I declared iteration i set it to zero because I know that arrays start at [0], so I don't know if that's the problem.

Comment: Did you move the iteration++ inside the if statement block, too? Otherwise you're going to incrementing it every time you press the mouse.

Comment: I did. I fixed it. In Tower.java i removed static from ints. x and y, and put `i` instead of `Controls.iteration` in the painter. Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's great. Sorry I missed that in your earlier comment.